# Sort an array by object property using StringComparer.Ordinal

Tags: c#, string, sorting, directoryinfo

I have read questions related to sorting an array of objects by property, but I have a special case where I need the aditional `StringComparer.Ordinal` object to perform a custom sort.

I have a `DirectoryInfo[]` array where I need the subdirectories to be sorted by their FullName property but I need the sorting order of the numbers contained in the paths to be:

1 - 2 - 4 - 10 - 14 - 25

instead of

1 - 10 - 14 - 2 - 25 - 4

(I have paths such as `c:\Folder\Subfolder\1`, `c:\Folder\Subfolder\2` ...)

I think this would be acomplished with: `Array.Sort(paths, StringComparer.Ordinal)` if my array was an array of strings.

How can I acomplish this if my array is an array of `DirectoryInfo[]`? I would like to avoid extending DirectoryInfo by creating a new class.

Comment: Create custom `IComparer` that would compare using `DirectoryInfo.FullName` and `StringComparer.Ordinal`?

Comment: For that I would have to create a class that extends DirectoryInfo and implements IComparer, wouldnt I? Is there another option?

Comment: No, it would just implement `IComparer`. Notice, it's not `IComparable` but `IComparer`. Precisely, you want `IComparer<T>`, and then use `Array.Sort<T> (T[], IComparer<T>)`

Comment: Well the duplicate marker only solves half of your problem. The other would be: `directoryInfoArray.OrderBy(s => s.FullName, MyComparer);`